# AuthStateListener callback is not triggering after reloading the firebase user on Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm having a little issue with FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener while working with email verification on Firebase. I've verified my email by clicking the received verification link, and then I reloaded the current user by the lines of code below:

```kotlin
suspend fun reloadUserInfo() {
    firebaseAuth.currentUser?.reload()?.await()
}
```

But AuthStateListener is not firing up even tho I reloaded the cached user. If I understood correctly AuthStateListener should trigger after reloading the current user. The reload() function's documentation says: `Manually refreshes the data of the current user (for example, attached providers, display name, and so on).` The `isEmailVerified` state changed the firebase user. Right?

```kotlin
val isEmailVerified: Flow<Boolean> = callbackFlow {
    val authStateListener = AuthStateListener { auth ->
        val isEmailVerified = auth.currentUser?.isEmailVerified == true
        trySend(isEmailVerified)
    }
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    awaitClose {
        firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }
}
```

This flow is not sending anything. But after restarting the application the callback gets fired. I don't want to restart the application to get the job done. It would not be a good user experience.

I did some research but nothing was found. If you take the time to help me, I appreciate it.

Comment: I also tried IdTokenListener callback but still not working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email verification happens out of the band, so when you click the link in the email, there is nothing built-in that triggers Firebase Authentication clients to be updated. So there is no callback for that. Firebase only refreshes the ID token once per hour. This means that it may take up to an hour before the token is refreshed, a case in which the `onIdTokenChanged()` method fires. So `onAuthStateChanged()` nor `onIdTokenChanged()` fires when the link is clicked, which basically means that we have to check that in our application code, on demand. Since you're using Kotlin, the solution is quite simple:

```
return try {
    auth.currentUser?.reload()?.await()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e(TAG, "${e.message}")
}
```

However, do **not** attach a complete listener and call `await()` at the same time. It's one or the other. Do **not** combine them! Why? Because there is no guarantee that the listener will be called before or after `await()`. That means that there is a chance that the code in the complete listener won't be called until or after the suspend function returns. Besides that, one of the major reasons to use [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) in the first place is to avoid using callbacks, which are not life-cycle aware.

If you want to see a concrete example, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).