# Android: Firebase email verification not working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

so i have this app which basically have a sign in screen that could navigate you to a sign up screen if you sign up your info gets stored in firebase auth and an email verification is to you and everthing is fine you go and verify your email then click continue in the app ,the app checks if the email is verified if true you be navigated to Home screen if false an error shown that indicates you have to verify the email this works fine.

but what doesn't is if you sign out then try to sign in the mecanism i put is if your email is verified you go to home screen if not you go to the same verify screen the problem is no matter what you get navigated to the verifiy screen even though the variable which is responsible for the Boolean for the state of the email(verified or not) is accually true so it should go to home screen.

> this is the code for the sign in composable:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

    Column(
        .....
    ) {
        
        OutlinedTextField(
               ...
            label = {
                Text(text = "Email")
            }
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            ...
            label = {
                Text(text = "Password")
            },
            
        LoadingTextButton(
            showLoadingState = viewModel.showLoadingState,
            text = "Sign In",
            padding = 16.dp
        ) {
            viewModel.onSignInWithEmailAndPasswordClick()
        }

when (val signInResponse = viewModel.emailAndPasswordSignInResponse) {
    is ResponseEmailPassword.Loading -> {
        viewModel.showLoadingState.value = true
    }

    is ResponseEmailPassword.Success -> {
        viewModel.showLoadingState.value = false
        val isUserSignedIn = signInResponse.data
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = isUserSignedIn) {
            if (isUserSignedIn) {
                viewModel.isEmailVerified()
                delay(500L)
                val isEmailVerified = viewModel.isEmailVerified
                Log.d("isEmailVerified", "sign in View: ${viewModel.isEmailVerified}")
                if (isEmailVerified) {
                    navController.navigate("home_Screen")
                } else {
                    navController.navigate("verifiy_email_Screen")
                }
            }
        }

    }

    is ResponseEmailPassword.Failure -> signInResponse.apply {
        viewModel.showLoadingState.value = false
        Log.d("checkSignIN", authErrors(e.message))
        viewModel.errorMessage.value = authErrors(e.message)

    }
}
```

> this is the viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SignInViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val emailPasswordRepo: EmailPasswordAuthRepository
) : ViewModel() {

var emailAndPasswordSignInResponse by mutableStateOf<SignInResponse>(ResponseEmailPassword.Success(false))

var showLoadingState = mutableStateOf(false)

var isEmailVerified by mutableStateOf(false)

fun isEmailVerified() {
    showLoadingState.value = true
    viewModelScope.launch {
        emailPasswordRepo.reloadFirebaseUser()
        isEmailVerified = emailPasswordRepo.currentUser?.isEmailVerified ?: false
        Log.d("isEmailVerified", "from sign in viewModel $isEmailVerified")
        showLoadingState.value = false
    }
}

fun onSignInWithEmailAndPasswordClick() = viewModelScope.launch {
    emailAndPasswordSignInResponse = ResponseEmailPassword.Loading
    emailAndPasswordSignInResponse = emailPasswordRepo.firebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword(
        emailTextFieldValue.value,
        passwordTextFieldValue.value
    )

}
```

> this the repository for all the methods used in the viewModel:

```
@Singleton
class EmailPasswordAuthRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth
) : EmailPasswordAuthRepository {
override val currentUser: FirebaseUser?
    get() = auth.currentUser

override suspend fun firebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: String,
    password: String
): SignInResponse {
    return try {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
        ResponseEmailPassword.Success(true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        ResponseEmailPassword.Failure(e)
    }
}

override suspend fun reloadFirebaseUser(): ReloadUserResponse {
    return try {
        auth.currentUser?.reload()?.await()
        Log.d("isEmailVerified", "reloadFirebaseUser: user reloaded ${auth.currentUser?.isEmailVerified}")
        ResponseEmailPassword.Success(true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("isEmailVerified", "reloadFirebaseUser Failure: ${e}")
        ResponseEmailPassword.Failure(e)
    }
}
```

> and these are the logs i got when running the app providing an already verified email:

```
reloadFirebaseUser Failure:
kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled;job=SupervisorJobImpl{Cancelling}@fb30f15
from sign in viewModel true
```

as you can see its true but still the app got me to the verify screen and also this Coroutine Cancellation Exception was thrown i think in "fun reloadFirebaseUser()" that is located in the repository which is probably caused by the await().
if you have any solution i would be gratfull and if need any more information i well gladlly provide it.

Comment: I don't spot the issue at a first glance but maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75112774/authstatelistener-callback-is-not-triggering-after-reloading-the-firebase-user-o/75116919#75116919) will help. Aside from that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. It's a working solution. Here is also the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Comment: now that i see your name i want to thank you because you are the one who wrote that article i followed to this it helped me so much, one thing which i don't understand in it is in "presentation/sign_in/components/SignIn.kt." what you did was "success ->Unit" and i don't understand how is that suppose to navigate me to the profile screen or to to anywhere else if you could explain the reason behind this i would appreciate it

Comment: When the auth state changes, the auth listener fires, in that case, we can [navigate](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword/blob/caa3b1f98cd65bc9698db4c18c744472f9ba1490/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebasesigninwithemailandpassword/presentation/MainActivity.kt#L36) to the specific screen.

Comment: @AlexMamo thank you now i understand and i have fixed the issue, but as always with this field another has accured but it's in dagger hilt so time to hit every stack overflow available